# Can I use INSERT inside CASE in postgres

Tags: postgresql, case, sql-insert

I am trying to create a function in postgres that would insert a row if it doesn't exist and return the row's id (newly created or existing).

I came up with this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION                                                      
get_enttype(name character varying, module character varying)               
RETURNS integer LANGUAGE SQL STABLE AS $$                                   
    SELECT typeid FROM enttypes WHERE name = $1 AND module = $2             
$$;                                                                             

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION                                                      
    ensure_enttype(name character varying, module character varying)            
    RETURNS integer LANGUAGE SQL AS $$                                          
    SELECT CASE WHEN get_enttype($1, $2) IS NULL                                
    THEN                                                                        
        INSERT INTO enttypes(name, module) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING typeid                                                 
    ELSE                                                                        
        get_enttype($1, $2)                                                     
    END                                                                         
$$;
```

It however raises a syntax  error because of `INSERT` inside `CASE`. I managed to fix this problem by creating a separate function with this `INSERT` and using this function in `CASE`. It works as expected, but this fix seems a little strange. My question is - can I fix this without creating another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use `INSERT` inside `CASE` in an `sql` function. You can, however:

- Use a PL/PgSQL function with `IF ... ELSE ... END` statements; or
- Use a writable common table expression (wCTE) or `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query

Answer (score 1):

Pure SQL can do it:

```
create or replace function  ensure_enttype(
    name character varying, module character varying
) returns integer language sql as $$

    insert into enttypes(name, module)
    select $1, $2
    where get_enttype($1, $2) is null
    ;
    select get_enttype($1, $2);
$$;
```

Comment: But will your code return the typeid if the record already exists?